# Adding random values across multiple columns with column names based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe and there are some columns that have NaNs. I want to replace those NaNs with random values, and I'm trying to come up with a fast way of doing it instead of applying my lambda function to each column at a time. I have a list of the column names that I would like to modify.

Here's what I have so far as an example:

```
df
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e  col_f
0      1      2      3    NaN    NaN    NaN
1      4      5      6    NaN    NaN    NaN
2      7      8      9    NaN    NaN    NaN

specific_columns = [col_d, col_e, col_f]

    for col in specific_columns in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(0,10))
```

Ideally I would want to see a df something like this:

```
   col_a  col_b  col_c  col_d  col_e  col_f
0      1      2      3      4      3      3
1      4      5      6      6      5      2
2      7      8      9      9      1      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```py
a = len(df.index)
b = len(df.columns)
nans = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(a,b), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

df.update(nans)
```

This will take numbers from normal dist and update your NaNs with values from it.

Comment: I just want to modify the columns that happen to be on my list, in this case, the specific_columns list. Although this does the trick, it updates all of my columns, and I want to avoid updating columns outside of what's in my list, especially if they have NaNs that I don't want to mess with.

Comment: you can populate random numbers from the list the same and update your dataframe with generated one:)